# Given an IP address and a Subnet, how do I calculate the range of IPs using php

Tags: php, ip-address, subnet

I have the following code snippet and im trying to detect if an IP address falls into a certain range. Most of the time I have the IP address and the subnet but sometimes I just have the IP address only.

```
<?php

function CalculateRange($IP,$Subnet=""){

    //Calculate subnetmax
    if ($Subnet==""){

    }        

    //Calculate max IP

    return $MaxIP;
}

//--- IP range
$IPRange = array (
    array("address"=>"196.201.26.0","subnet"=>"255.255.252.0"),
    array("address"=>"196.202.43.0","subnet"=>"255.255.0.0"),
    array("address"=>"196.203.44.0","subnet"=>"255.255.128.0"),
);

//Display MaxIP for each IP and Subnet
foreach ($IPRange as $pair) {
    echo "<p>";
    echo "For IP:{$pair['address']} with Subnet:{$pair['subnet']}.";
    echo "MaxIP is ";
    echo CalculateRange($pair['address'],$pair['subnet']);  
    echo "</p>";
}

?>
```

My question is how do I calculate MaxIP for the IP and Subnet combo?

Comment: Be sure to check out the [`ip2long`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) php-function! Also read about the [`&`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator for bitwise comparisons.

Comment: According to my understandings, you cannot calculate MaxIP or the subnet mask from an IP address as the operation is opposite. You require subnet mask to tell the range of IPs that lie in it.

Comment: @RajaAmerKhan he does have the subnet

Comment: @RajaAmerKhan I have the subnet in most occasions. Forgive me if my question seems silly but I'm no networking guru :(. Basically, when an IP comes in I need to be able to check if it's a valid IP by checking if it falls into a valid IP range.

Comment: @DeAn, in the cases where no subnet mask is provided, you won't be able to check. Technically you need to check the first IP as well. The first and the last IP address of a subnet can not be used, also the IP addresses you provided are not valid.

Comment: If you're interested in Subnetting, [here's a great link](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a00800a67f5.shtml).

Comment: @DanFromGermany Sorry I misunderstood the question. To DeAn, I have created a test code for you, you may have a look at it. I don't say it's correct but I feel it will help you solving your problem. I haven't practiced networking for a long time so my networking skills have weaken a bit. Pardon me for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below worked perfectly

```
function isInRange() {

    //--- IP range
    $IPRange = array (
        array("address"=>"197.207.35.238","subnet"=>"255.255.0.0"),
        array("address"=>"41.207.44.232","subnet"=>"255.255.10.0"),
        array("address"=>"40.207.44.250","subnet"=>"255.255.0.0")
    );

    foreach ($IPRange as $pair) {

        //Check if we have subnet mask
        if ($pair['subnet']!='') {
            // simple example
            $bcast = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            $smask = ip2long($pair['subnet']);
            $nmask = $bcast & $smask;
            $SourceStartIP = long2ip($nmask);

            if($SourceStartIP==$pair['address']) {
                //This is in range
                return true;
            }

        } else {

            //--- The header matches something in the fixed list
            if ($pair['address'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {

                return true;

            }

        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$subnet = "255.255.252.0";  // provide your subnet here
$ip = "191.168.31.0";   // provide your ip here
$ip_blocks = explode(".", $ip);
$mask_blocks = explode('.', $subnet);

$ip_class = '';
if($ip_blocks[0] > 0 && $ip_blocks[0] <= 126) {
    $ip_class = 'a';
} elseif($ip_blocks[0] >= 128 && $ip_blocks[0] <= 191) {
    $ip_class = 'b';
} elseif($ip_blocks[0] >= 192 && $ip_blocks[0] <= 223) {
    $ip_class = 'c';
} elseif($ip_blocks[0] >= 224 && $ip_blocks[0] <= 239) {
    $ip_class = 'd';
} elseif($ip_blocks[0] >= 240 && $ip_blocks[0] <= 255) {
    $ip_class = 'e';
} else {
    die('wrong ip');
}

$subnet_class= '';
if($mask_blocks[0]=='255' && $mask_blocks[1] < '255') {
    $subnet_class = 'a';
} elseif($mask_blocks[0]=='255' && $mask_blocks[1]=='255' && $mask_blocks[2] < '255') {
    $subnet_class = 'b';
} else {
    $subnet_class = 'c';
}

echo 'subnet class: '.$subnet_class.'<br />';

$min_ip = '';
$max_ip = '';

if($subnet_class=='b') {
    if($ip_class == $subnet_class) {
        $min_ip = "$ip_blocks[0].$ip_blocks[1].1";
        $max_ip = "$ip_blocks[0].$ip_blocks[1].255";
        echo 'minimum: '.$min_ip.' - maximum: '.$max_ip;
    } else {
        echo 'Error! IP does not lie in this range. ';
        exit;   
    }   
}
// you can continue for other subnet masks as well.. as this is only for subnet for class b

?>
```

Comment: Just want to let you know that `$ip_blocks[0] >= 0` needs to be `$ip_blocks[0] > 0`. You can't use 0 as an IP. More info here on [Subnet Zero](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080093f18.shtml)