# Check if string is ip subnet

Tags: php, regex, ip, subnet

I have list of ip addresses as string, but there are some subnets in that list too. 
For example:

...
`127.0.0.1`     (this is ip)
`127.0.0.1/24`  (this is subnet)
...

I want to check which is ip and which is subnet. So far I can filter ip but I couldn`t find a way to check subnet:

```
foreach ($ipstrings as $ip) {
        if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false){
            $ips[] = $ip;
        }
        elseif (is_subnet) {
            $subnets[] = $ip;
        }
    }
```

How can make is_subnet work?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733285/given-an-ip-address-and-a-subnet-how-do-i-calculate-the-range-of-ips-using-php

Comment: Your "network" is incorrect. `127.0.0.1` is __not__ a correct net address (for which netmask 24 can be applied). Fix it to `127.0.0.0`. Then split your network into to parts: `127.0.0.0` and `24`. Then convert 24 into corresponding bits. After this check is: `HOST & MASK = NET`. If it's correct, answer is "belongs"

Comment: I just gave sample numbers, it can be any ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

// array of ip and subnets
$ipandmask = array('127.0.0.1','127.0.0.0','127.0.0.2','127.0.0.3/24','127.0.0.4/16'); 

foreach ($ipandmask as $ipmask) {

        if(preg_match('~^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9][0-9]~',$ipmask,$subnet)){
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Subnet =>";
        print_r ($subnet);

    }

        if(preg_match('~^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}~',$ipmask,$ip)){
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Ip =>";
        print_r ($ip);

    }

}


    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted was just this part of your code : preg_match('~^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9][0-9]~',$ipmask,$subnet)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1/124';
$subnet = '';
if (preg_match('~^(.+?)/([^/]+)$~', $ip, $m)) {
   $ip = $m[1];
   $subnet = $m[2];
}
echo filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) . ", $subnet";
```

Comment: Not my habit to post code without testing. See working demo: http://ideone.com/XAgYgC Most likely codepad is using some very old PHP version.

Comment: Okay sorry. Could you tell a bit more on what your regex is doing (what rule is that being matched), I am not very good at understanding regex, please

Comment: Ya sure. Regex attempts to break IP string by finding text before and after `/`. If `preg_match` is successful then it means subnet was found. Captured group #1 will be actual IP address and captured group #2 will be subnet in that case. If `preg_match` is not successful then it is regular IP and `$subnet` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
<?php
$ip="127.0.0.1/25";
$x = explode("/",$ip);
print_r($x);
if (isset($x[1])){
    echo"subnet";
} else {echo "ip";}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah this is similar to something I have done already, but it is not the best way, because $ip may contain some characters which should not be taken as subnet or ip